# clientside localisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a colleague who thinks this

```
alert('<asp:Localize ID="ErrorAddingComponent" runat="server" Text="There was an error adding component: "  meta:resourcekey="ErrorAddingComponent"/>' + errortext);
```

is a good idea if we get an error from an AJAX call, the errortext is the parameter of the function called on error from a jquery ajax,

to me the thought of using a server side localize control seems horrible, we are using asp.net MVC so, for me, even using the GetLocalResourceObject is prefereable to this,

can anyone give me any reasons I can raise this with him? (or if you believe his solution is ok why?).

As an aside the alert annoys me too, I believe we should parse errors to a div for presentation.

Comment: I think what I wanted from this was someone to give me more details on why this is bad, I feel it is but at the end of the day the localize control does parse a string that will alert if the alert is fired (as far as Javascript is concerned the string could have been hardcoded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alerts = -1

a div is nice, and not annoying, plus, you  can offer multiple solutions, links as, try again, or ignore, or start over.

If you use an alert, it looks ugly, and you only provide limited options to the user.

Comment: I like the explanation of how we can use the div to provide alternatives, the alert is just ugly!